# How big does DB need to become for PHP/mySQL to be noticably slow?

Tags: mysql, performance, database-performance

I'm wondering if there are any developers out there who have experience doing this:

How many rows (in a table with 1 column, primary key) can you have before queries becomes slow?  Is it something I don't need to worry about?  I probably won't ever have more than 5000 or so.  I don't have enough experience to know.

Comment: This is a bad idea and an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). People blindly following into solving Y, when X needs critical and rational review.

Comment: Well... the x problem is ... how to authenticate  a device/app instance without the user explicitly supplying credentials... that is, not having to "sign in."  Youre right i should have just thought about that first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is based more on your title "how big does DB need to become for PHP/mySQL to be noticably slow".

PHP...

If you are fetching one row, then all the time is in MySQL.  If you are fetching an entire table, then a lot of the cost is in PHP.  5000 rows is not bad.  A million rows would be slow and probably run out of RAM.

MySQL...

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE primary_key = 'constant';
```

will be 'instantaneous' even if there are a *billion* rows in the table.

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE non_indexed_column = 'constant';
```

will begin to be slow at 5000 rows, will take "too long" at a million rows, and take hours or days if you have a billion rows.

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE indexed_uuid = 'constant';
```

Although this is 'instantaneous', it becomes I/O bound as the table grows.  UUIDs are very random, hence caching is an issue.  When the index is small enough to fit in RAM, this performs well.  As the index gets bigger, the statement gets slower.  [*More on the evils of UUIDs*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/uuid).

*In other words, you deleted important information -- namely that UUIDs are involved.*

Why have a 1-column table for checking the UUID?  Why not have an index in some other table, and use it for checking.  Performance will be virtually the same (good it cacheable, I/O-bound if not).

Answer (score 1):

If it's indexed (and it should be; as the only field in the table, it should be the primary key), you have a massive amount of breathing room as far as database capacity goes. It's based on your server and software configuration, technically, but even MySQL is not going to break a sweat on a single table with a single UUID per row and 5,000 rows.

On the PHP end, it also depends on your server resources and the capacity of your connection compared to the bandwidth your requests are occupying... but if you're working on a table that's unlikely to store more than 5,000ish records, it seems unlikely the associated PHP is going to have capacity problems (provided your clients are making a sane number of requests).

A couple notes, though:

You seem to be implying the client (web client? Mobile client? Gas station client?) will be generating the UUID, which is then validated on the server... this isn't really authentication, or any assurance of authenticity. It's not clear what your use case is, but you may want to step back, define your goals for this token, and look around for people who have solved the same problem. If you're generating something like an API key or authentication token, a simple shared UUID likely is not the best way to go about it. In any case, this should happen over SSL, otherwise you're trivially handing out your credentials to anyone who's listening to your requests.

Less importantly, depending on whether or not your token needs to be persistent across sessions, which is also something I'm not clear on from your description, you may not need database persistence for it. An in-memory store like redis might be something worth looking into, though again, I don't get the impression performance is going to be a bottleneck based on your estimate.

Given what you've said, it's impossible to estimate capacity, but it strikes me as unlikely that you're going to run into any kind of bottleneck from your technology stack.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time... there aren't any credentials that are at risk... it's more me just protecting myself against people using a browser to directly interact with the php pages ... as opposed to with the app (it's android).  this question has to do with an earlier question I asked here:

Comment: This actually won't prevent that (unless you're using SSL, but this still isn't really a great course of action, which is why I think you should look further into existing solutions). You shouldn't actually care about the source of requests; it may seem counterintuitive, but since you can never 100% confirm where requests are coming from, your PHP should just rely on whatever authentication mechanism you're using. At most, for this method, someone would just have to mimic the initial request and keep using the UUID they send you, so this likely isn't sufficient for your use case.